# Swift using Modulo 97 for IBAN Converter

Tags: swift, xcode, modulo, iban

**Hey**,

I want to build a IBAN converter tool for IPhones. What I mean by that is that the User has 2 textfield. One for the `bank code` and one for the `account number`.

To get the right **IBAN** I have to put the "Checksum" e.g `700901001234567890131400` and use the modulos 97 to get the "check digit"
in this example it is `08`.

In php it looks like this:

```
$mod97 = bcmod($checkSum, "97");
```

**How can I achieve the same result in Swift?**

PS:

1. Account Number: `1234567890`
2. Bank Account  :`70090100`

*These are not real just to mention it!*

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803956/iban-validator-swift-3 ?

Comment: I dont want to check if it's valid or not